# Ambigious dop down menu on hovering in css

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i am working on a website and the site has a few links like home, about us, contact us, pharma, vets. now if the user hovers on the products link i want it to display a drop down of items where on selection goes to respective pages.

here is my html part:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.html" class="current"><span></span>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="" target=""><span></span>CPPL Pharma</a>
<ul id="templatemo_menu"><li><a href=""><span></span>Category 1</a><ul><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 1</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 2</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 3</a></li></ul></li>
<li><a href=""><span></span>Category 2</a><ul><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 4</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 5</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 6</a></li></ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="" target=""><span></span>CPPL Vets</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html"><span></span>About Us</a></li>        
<li><a href="contactus.html"><span></span>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my css part:

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
    background: #ffffff;
}

a:link, a:visited { color: #0066CC; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; } 
a:active, a:hover { color: #990000; text-decoration: underline; }

p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

img { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; }

.cleaner { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0px; font-size: 0px;  }

.cleaner_h10 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 10px; }
.cleaner_h20 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 20px; }
.cleaner_h30 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 30px; }
.cleaner_h40 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 40px; }
.cleaner_h50 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 50px; }
.cleaner_h60 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 60px; }

.margin_r_20 { margin-right: 20px; }

.margin_r_40 { margin-right: 40px; }

.button_01 a {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 57px;
    height: 23px;
    padding: 2px 5px 0 22px;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/button_01.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.button_01 a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(images/button_01_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
}

ul > li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative; 
    padding:0.5em; 
    line-height:1em
}
ul ul {
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2em;
    left:0;
}
ul ul > li {
    float:left;
}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {
    display:block;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 2px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ba0808;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
}

.image_wrapper {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #e8e8e8;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #fff;
}

.fl_image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px 
}

.fr_image {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px 
}



#site_title_bar_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background:  url(images/site_title_bg_wrapper.jpg) repeat-x top;
}

#site_title_bar {
    width: 940px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: url(images/site_title_bg.jpg) no-repeat top;
}

#site_title {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#site_title h1 a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #ba0808;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_title h1 a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;  
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_title h1 a span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #204567;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


#site_title_bar #menu {
    float: right;
    width: 540px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666; 
    outline: none;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_right.jpg) center right no-repeat;
}

#menu li a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_left.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li .current {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_right_hover.jpg) center right;
}

#menu li a:hover span, #menu li .current span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_left_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
}


#site_title_bar #search_box {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#search_box form {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#searchfield {
    height: 20px;
    width: 195px;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #666666;  
}

#searchbutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px 0 9px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: pre;
    color: #2b3844;
}


#banner_wrapper_outter {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: url(images/banner_bg_wrapper_outter.jpg) top repeat-x;
}

#banner_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: url(images/banner_bg_wrapper.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#banner {
    width: 960px;
    height: 410px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/banner_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#banner_slider {
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 70px 0 0 0;
    background: none;
}


#content {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    background: url(images/content_bg_middle.png) repeat-y center;
}

#content #twitter_section {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content #twitter_section p {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 34px;
    color: #2a90c1;
}

#content #twitter_section .followme a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat;
}


#content p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 0 29px 0 0;
}

.box_border {
    border-right: 1px dotted #999;
}

.box h2 {
    color: #9b1919;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box .box_image_wrapper {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.em_text {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}

.section_w940 {
    clear: both;
    width: 940px;
}


.section_w450 {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}

.news_box{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc; 
    color: #2f5e9e;
}

.news_box .post_info {
    color: #666;
}

.news_box .post_info a {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.news_box .post_info strong {
    color: #000000;
}

.news_box a {
    color: #2f5e9e;
}

.testimonial {
    font-style: italic;
}


#footer_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #677684 url(images/footer_bg.jpg) repeat-x top;
}

#footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 10px 20px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer  a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer .section_w240 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#footer .section_w240 h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;

}

#footer .footer_list {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}


#footer .footer_list li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

#footer .footer_list li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer .footer_list li a:hover {
    color: #FFFF00;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

here is my problem's screenshot : http://imageshack.com/a/img268/8717/3fsb.png

i want category 2 to come below category 1 and so on!! how to do this??

Comment: Here's a fiddle from your code. I don't see the problem you show in your image. http://jsfiddle.net/zwg7t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that guy answered it anyhow... Here's the full code
(with a couple tags to test, save as a .html and see for yourself. Good Luck!):

```
<!--language:HTML -->
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
    background: #000;    /*CHANGE THIS BACKGROUND VALUE BACK TO: #FFF; */
}

a:link, a:visited { color: #0066CC; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; } 
a:active, a:hover { color: #990000; text-decoration: underline; }

p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

img { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; }

.cleaner { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0px; font-size: 0px;  }

.cleaner_h10 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 10px; }
.cleaner_h20 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 20px; }
.cleaner_h30 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 30px; }
.cleaner_h40 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 40px; }
.cleaner_h50 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 50px; }
.cleaner_h60 { clear: both; width:100%; height: 60px; }

.margin_r_20 { margin-right: 20px; }

.margin_r_40 { margin-right: 40px; }

.button_01 a {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 57px;
    height: 23px;
    padding: 2px 5px 0 22px;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(images/button_01.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.button_01 a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(images/button_01_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
}

ul > li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative; 
    padding:0.5em; 
    line-height:1em
}
ul ul {
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2em;
    left:0;
}
ul ul > li {
/* float:none; is pointless, just remove the float property, Add display: block; */
display:block;    
}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {
    display:block;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 2px 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ba0808;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
}

.image_wrapper {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #e8e8e8;
    padding: 1px;
    background: #fff;
}

.fl_image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px 
}

.fr_image {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px 
}



#site_title_bar_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background:  url(images/site_title_bg_wrapper.jpg) repeat-x top;
}

#site_title_bar {
    width: 940px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: url(images/site_title_bg.jpg) no-repeat top;
}

#site_title {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

#site_title h1 a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #ba0808;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_title h1 a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;  
    text-decoration: none;
}

#site_title h1 a span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #204567;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


#site_title_bar #menu {
    float: right;
    width: 540px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
/* Added the > greater-than symbol to this CSS decleration below, as suggested by @chadocat */
#menu > li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666; 
    outline: none;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_right.jpg) center right no-repeat;
}

#menu li a span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_left.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li .current {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_right_hover.jpg) center right;
}

#menu li a:hover span, #menu li .current span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/menu_bg_left_hover.jpg) no-repeat;
}


#site_title_bar #search_box {
    float: right;
    width: 280px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#search_box form {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#searchfield {
    height: 20px;
    width: 195px;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #666666;  
}

#searchbutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px 0 9px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: pre;
    color: #2b3844;
}


#banner_wrapper_outter {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: url(images/banner_bg_wrapper_outter.jpg) top repeat-x;
}

#banner_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: url(images/banner_bg_wrapper.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#banner {
    width: 960px;
    height: 410px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(images/banner_bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#banner_slider {
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 70px 0 0 0;
    background: none;
}


#content {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    background: url(images/content_bg_middle.png) repeat-y center;
}

#content #twitter_section {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#content #twitter_section p {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 34px;
    color: #2a90c1;
}

#content #twitter_section .followme a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat;
}


#content p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    padding: 0 29px 0 0;
}

.box_border {
    border-right: 1px dotted #999;
}

.box h2 {
    color: #9b1919;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box .box_image_wrapper {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.em_text {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}

.section_w940 {
    clear: both;
    width: 940px;
}


.section_w450 {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}

.news_box{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc; 
    color: #2f5e9e;
}

.news_box .post_info {
    color: #666;
}

.news_box .post_info a {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.news_box .post_info strong {
    color: #000000;
}

.news_box a {
    color: #2f5e9e;
}

.testimonial {
    font-style: italic;
}


#footer_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #677684 url(images/footer_bg.jpg) repeat-x top;
}

#footer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 10px 20px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer  a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer .section_w240 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

#footer .section_w240 h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;

}

#footer .footer_list {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}


#footer .footer_list li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

#footer .footer_list li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer .footer_list li a:hover {
    color: #FFFF00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.html" class="current"><span></span>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="" target=""><span></span>CPPL Pharma</a>
<ul id="templatemo_menu"><li><a href=""><span></span>Category 1</a><ul><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 1</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 2</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 3</a></li></ul></li>
<li><a href=""><span></span>Category 2</a><ul><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 4</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 5</a></li><li><a href=""><span></span>Product 6</a></li></ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="" target=""><span></span>CPPL Vets</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html"><span></span>About Us</a></li>        
<li><a href="contactus.html"><span></span>Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help sir really appreciated!! but still the prob persists!! am getting same thing!! :/

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help sir! but doesnt seem to work for me :/ never mind i ll change the whole css!!

Comment: Ah, well... if you need help, I can go through it with you over teamviewer & skype or something?

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example website: http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/

CSS:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    RESET
\*------------------------------------*/
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img{
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var{
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
caption,th{
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after{
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym{
    border:0;
}


/*------------------------------------*\
    MAIN
\*------------------------------------*/
html{
    height:101%;
    background:#fff url(/img/css/bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
}
body{
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:0.75em;
    color:#333;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    NAV
\*------------------------------------*/
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /* Clear floats */
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    /* Bring the nav above everything else--uncomment if needed.
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    */
}
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
#nav ul{
    background:#fff; /* Adding a background makes the dropdown work properly in IE7+. Make this as close to your page's background as possible (i.e. white page == white background). */
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); /* But! Let's make the background fully transparent where we can, we don't actually want to see it if we can help it... */
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display:none;) */
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; /* Introducing a padding between the li and the a give the illusion spaced items */
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; /* Stop text wrapping and creating multi-line dropdown items */
}
#nav li:hover ul{ /* Display the dropdown on hover */
    left:0; /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
}
#nav li:hover a{ /* These create persistent hover states, meaning the top-most link stays 'hovered' even when your cursor has moved down the list. */
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ /* The persistent hover state does however create a global style for links even before they're hovered. Here we undo these effects. */
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ /* Here we define the most explicit hover states--what happens when you hover each individual link. */
    background:#333;
}

h1{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    width:520px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html><head><link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">The product</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Services</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice two</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Sevice three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sevice four</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (one)</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Small product (two)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (three)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Small product (four)</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Big product (five)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Big product (six)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Big product (seven)</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Big product (eight)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enormous product (nine)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enormous product (ten)</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Enormous product (eleven)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Out-of-hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul></body></html>
```

Comment: If you have any other questions related to this CSS, just ask ;)

Comment: but the position of my drop down and buttons is totally diff from urs sir!! can u help me do it for mine?? i am new to this stuff!!

Comment: Sure, Sorry I thought you just required the logistics... I will have a look at this after work, say around 5.45pm GMT+0 London Time.

All you need to do is chop and change the css properties.. I will do it for you later and give you an explanation.

Comment: thanks mate!! i have updated the question and given my full css file for reference...and a small request can u make it asap? coz based on that is my whole site

Comment: Oh **** I forgot, It slipped my mind, I will have a look asap *oh-dear*.